# How to assign checkbox in JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing grid view load on demand using JavaScript and JSON.

```
   function OnSuccess(response) {
        debugger;
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        pageCount = parseInt(xml.find("PageCount").eq(0).find("PageCount").text());
        var customers = xml.find("Quotes");
        $("[id$=gridPolicyNumbers] .loader").remove();
        customers.each(function () {
            var customer = $(this);
             var row = "<tr>" +
            **"Place check box code here"**+
            "<td>" + customer.find("PolicyNumber").text() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + customer.find("QuoteNumber").text() +
            "</td><td>" + customer.find("InsuredName").text() +
            "</td><td>" + customer.find("EffectiveDate").text() +
            "</td><td>" + customer.find("ExpireDate").text() +
            "</td><td>" + customer.find("LineCode").text() + "</td>"
            + "</tr>";

            $("[id$=gridPolicyNumbers]").append(row);
            //alert(row.text);

        });
```

Here i have to add first column as check box.

Can any one suggest how to do..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might check the basics first before you do stuff like this. Have a look a [this example here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_checkbox) . Better get some HTML basics real quick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of `**"Place check box code here"**+` all you need to do is:

`"<td><input type='checkbox' name='check1' value='Check Me'/></td>"`

Comment: Thank you, How to get the check box id in code behind?

Comment: to this itself, add an id attribute, like so: `<td><input type='checkbox' id='check1' name='check1' value='Check Me'></td>`

Comment: by doing so, the value can be accessed using `check1`.

Comment: you should probably close your input tag

Answer (score 0):

```
"<td><input type='checkbox' /></td>"
```

Comment: normally we give name and value attribute to checkbox , or we cannot get back the value during form submission

Comment: @ShivanRaptor sorry, i assumed that the op would know how to add attributes to an html element.